# Setting TextBlock Text in Code Behind Gives NullReferenceException

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8, slider, textblock

I have a `TextBlock` control on my page in which I would like to set the value in the code behind, but I am getting a `NullReferenceException`. The value of the TextBlock changes according to the current position of a Slider Control. To note, the page never gets fully NavigatedTo when the error occurs. I'm not sure what I can do to solve this, any ideas?

XAML

```
<TextBlock x:Name="OpacityNumberTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center">
<Slider x:Name="MenuOpacitySlider"  Minimum="1" Maximum="6" Margin="12,20,12,0" 
                    ValueChanged="MenuOpacitySlider_ValueChanged" Value="1"/>
```

Code Behind

```
public void MenuOpacitySlider_ValueChanged(object sender, RoutedPropertyChangedEventArgs<double> e)
    {
        Slider slider = sender as Slider;

        //Round the value so it is a whole number even when the slider is dragged
        slider.Value = Math.Round(slider.Value);

        num = (int)slider.Value;

        switch (num)
        {
            case 1:
                OpacityNumberTextBlock.Text = "1"; //NullReferenceException
                break;
            ..
        }
    }
```

Comment: Maybe you try to subscribe to ValueChanged before InitializeComponent()?

Comment: @Matthew, is slider value really equal to '1'? What's the default behavior for switch-case scenario?

Comment: I just added my Slider control as an edit above to my original post. I actually have 6 cases in total, it just stops at the first one.

Comment: Removing the setting of OpacityNumberTextBlock in the ValueChanged event removes the error, and I am able to set the TextBlock in the OnNavigatedTo event just fine. But I need the TextBlock text to change as the slider control changes from 1-6.

Comment: I've created a test project, this code works fine, the textblock value changes correctly. The problem should be somewhere else.

Comment: The code works very fine in my case ..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `ValueChanged` is fired in `InitializeComponent()` while the `TextBlock` is null. Subscribe after `InitializeComponent()`:

In XAML:

```
<TextBlock x:Name="OpacityNumberTextBlock" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
<Slider x:Name="MenuOpacitySlider"  Minimum="1" Maximum="6" Margin="12,20,12,0" Value="1"/>
```

In code behind:

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    MenuOpacitySlider.ValueChanged+=MenuOpacitySlider_ValueChanged;
}
```

Comment: Ok i'll try this. Should I remove this from the XAML as well?

Comment: @Matthew yes - remove subscription from Slider in xaml (like in the code above)